# wrong hashing string to sha256 all line in text area

Tags: javascript, hash, textarea, sha256

Help me to hash my string to sha256.

I have script hashing and work, but I see problem, when I want to display a hashing result from all line in the textarea.

```
<form action="#" method="post">My string:<br/>
  <textarea type="text" id="string" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea><br/>
  <button id="encrypt">Encrypt</button>
  <p>SHA256 hashing:</p><br/>
  <textarea type="text" id="hash256" rows="1" cols="90"></textarea><br/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // MY SHA256 JAVASCRIPT HERE function SHA256(s) bla bla bla

  document.getElementById('encrypt').onclick = function() {
    var string = document.getElementById('string').value;
    // gets data from input text
    document.getElementById('hash256').value = SHA256(string);
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

I want to generate output the hash once in three rows

ex :

> insert
>
> line 1 > blue
>
> line 2 > orange
>
> line 3 > green

output in one click

> line 1 >
>   16477688c0e00699c6cfa4497a3612d7e83c532062b64b250fed8908128ed548
>
> line 2 >
>   1b4c9133da73a711322404314402765ab0d23fd362a167d6f0c65bb215113d94
>
> line 3 >
>   ba4788b226aa8dc2e6dc74248bb9f618cfa8c959e0c26c147be48f6839a0b088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lines = document.getElementById('string').value.split('\n');

for (var i=0; i <= lines.length; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById('hash256').value += 'line ' + i +' >' + SHA256(lines[i]);
}
```

This is not tested but should works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure your hashing script works ok maybe problem is with data.
Try

```
document.getElementById('hash256').value = SHA256(string.toString());
```